# Segmentation fault when calling pthread_create from wrapper class

Tags: c++, linux, class, pthreads

I'm writing Java-styled Thread class and I'm stuck because when my wrapper function casts received void pointer to Runnable pointer it causes segmentation fault, because the program doesn't know which run() to call.
I tried different casts, I tried to pass struct, containing pointer to Runnable, but in all cases it works like Russian Roulette: segfault with almost 100%, but also may work well, especially on the first run in gdb.

```
#include <pthread.h>
class Runnable {

    public:
        virtual void run() {};
        virtual ~Runnable() {};

};

static void* __outerwrapper(void* arg) {
    ( reinterpret_cast<Runnable*>(arg) )->run();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

class Thread : public Runnable {

    public:
        Thread() : target(this) {};
        Thread(Runnable* target) : target(target) {};
        void start() {
            pthread_create(&(this->thread), NULL, __outerwrapper, this->target);
        }
    private:
        Runnable* target;
        pthread_t thread;

};

int main () {
    Thread t;
    t.start();
}
```

I'd like to use that interface, but what do I need to change in order to make it work?

Comment: Why does `Thread` inherit from `Runnable` and also have a member pointer to a `Runnable`?

Comment: Sounds like someone's trying to transplant the madness that is Java threading into C++.

Comment: That class is meant to run some Runnable's method in new thread, either it will be a Runnable passed on creation, or it will be a class inherited from Thread.

Comment: Why is it madness, if that api is almost the same with c++11's stl threads?

Comment: The segfault is probably caused by the program finishing before your thread. Try putting a 'sleep' in the run method, or (more correctly) joining the thread at the end of main.

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem and I understood where's the  problem in real code!

Comment: Do not use `reinterpret_cast`. You want `static_cast` for this.

Comment: @sje397: It would have been nicer to add a `join()` method to `Thread` (calling the obvious: `pthread_join(thread, 0)`) and do `t.join()` as final statement in `main()`.